# Compare data frames python matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, dataframe

I have a simple question. I need to compare different trajectories made by different cars. So, I have different .csv files of different length containing different routes made by the different cars over the time.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read.csv("car1_route0.csv") 
df1 = pd.read.csv("car1_route1.csv")
df =
lat            lon
48.787834   11.383918
48.788124   11.384003
48.787849   11.383751

df1 =
48.787834   11.383918
48.788124   11.384003
48.787849   11.383751
48.787849   12.000000
```

At the end I would like to have a data frame that contains all the points counting the number of time people goes trough that point.

```
out =
lat         lon         time
48.787834   11.383918    2
48.788124   11.384003    2
48.787849   11.383751    2
48.787849   12.000000    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` your dfs after reading them in, then `groupby` on 'lat' and 'lon' and then call `size` to return the count, `reset_index` to restore your grouped columns and finally rename the generated column `0` to 'time':

```
In [8]:
merged = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
merged

Out[8]:
         lat        lon
0  48.787834  11.383918
1  48.788124  11.384003
2  48.787849  11.383751
3  48.787834  11.383918
4  48.788124  11.384003
5  48.787849  11.383751
6  48.787849  12.000000

In [15]:
merged.groupby(['lat','lon']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'time'})

Out[15]:
         lat        lon  time
0  48.787834  11.383918     2
1  48.787849  11.383751     2
2  48.787849  12.000000     1
3  48.788124  11.384003     2
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.